# Not able to click the "Choose File" button in selenium webdriver. The upload window for file is not opening

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was supposed to click a " Choose File " button on a website and it is supposed to open a window that allows me to choose the file but the window does not open even if I code it to click the element.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\shash\eclipse-wo"); 

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

driver.navigate().to("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload"); 

Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement uploadPhotoBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='file-upload']")) 

uploadPhotoBtn.click();
```

after this upload, the window should open but it's not.

Comment: File upload & download dialogs belongs to operating system not to browser. That's why are those not reachable by selenium.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file">
```

The HTML tag type is `input` instead of click you can directly send the file location to the `element`.

**Code**:

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement uploadPhotoBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='file-upload']"));
    uploadPhotoBtn.sendKeys("C:\\Sample.json");
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try with **Actions**, like below:

```
Imports Required 
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload");
        
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        
WebElement uploadPhotoBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='file-upload']"));
actions.moveToElement(uploadPhotoBtn).click().perform();
```

Comment: Won't work bcs file upload & download dialogs belongs to operating system not to browser. That's why are those not reachable by selenium.